# Not printing required result

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

When trying to test with SOAP UI..I coudn't get correct output for :

public String registerUserByuser(String user)
public String getAllUsers(String userNames)

```
User.java

package com.ws.entity;

public class User implements java.io.Serializable{

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    private String userName;
    private int userId;


}
===============================================================================
RegistrationService.java

package com.ws.Service;

import com.ws.entity.User;

public interface RegistrationService {
    String registerUserByuser (String user);
    User getuserNameById(int Id );
    String getAllUsers (String userNames);

}
===============================================================================

RegistrationServiceImpl.java

package com.ws.test;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

import com.ws.Service.RegistrationService;
import com.ws.entity.User;

@WebService(name = "UserWS", serviceName="RegService", portName = "CustomerPort", targetNamespace = "http://www.reg.com")
public class RegistrationServiceImpl implements RegistrationService {

    @WebMethod
    @Override
    public String registerUserByuser(String user) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        User u = new User();
        u.setUserId(555);
        u.setUserName("Keith");
        return user;
    } 

    @WebMethod
    @Override
    public User getuserNameById(int Id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        User a = new User();
        a.setUserId(888);
        a.setUserName("Seth");
        return a;
    }

    @WebMethod
    @Override
    public String getAllUsers(String userNames) {
        return userNames;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Requirement is to develop Bottom Up WebServices:
UserRegistration - Interface

method 1 - registerUser that takes user as input and sends String as output
method 2- getUser that takes id as input and returns back user object
method 3 - getAllusers that returns list of users back to user

Am I writing code in incorrect way?

Comment: What do you mean... of course getAllUsers isn't returning a list... it's just returning the input args for the method. I see no list/array anywhere in your code...

Comment: In the code I have provided above..how can I print users by adding array?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems more a mockup than an actual implementation. You are hardcoding the user you return in the getuserNameById method and you also have the mistake pointed out by Invexity in the getAllUsers method.

You need some form of persistence. For prototyping, you could just add a List attribute to your class, to store the users you create. Something like:

```
private List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
```

and in the registerUserByUser method do something like:

```
this.users.add(user);
```

Finally, in the getAllUsers method, you could just:

```
return this.users;
```

However, if this is some sort of mockup or test, it would be alright I guess. But if you are building production code, you need to read some more about webservices, persistence and security (given the fact that your domain is about users). This code is definitely not suitable for production for many reasons (hardcoding, lack of actual persistence, security of data, to name a few).